# JQuery iterating through 10 JSON items at a time, loading 10 more with a button

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I've got a simple JSON feed of news items with a headline, a photo, a link, etc. I'm able to build a each function that'll run them all through and create a simple enough little div with a thumbnail photo, working link, etc. But in this feed I've got seven days' worth of news items. I can do this all at once, but it slows down the load speed, obviously.

So what I want to do is have 10 or some similar set number load on opening the page and then have a "Load More" button that adds the next 10 items, another at the end of that, etc.

I've seen quite a few examples of how to do this in basically loading all of these items into a div with a display of none and then using a button to load X number of them. But that still leads to some slow-ish load times if I go that route with maybe 150 items, no? What's the best method for this and can someone point me to a simple example?

Comment: have you tried lazy loading plugin?

Comment: No, I've not come across that one. I'm pretty new to this stuff. I'll go try it out and report back. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use 'Lazy Loading' or 'On Demand' concept here to increase the performance and reduce the number of post backs to server. Its similar to paging in grid view/table. You have to set index and size. i.e index = 0 and size = 5, which means for the first time 5 news will be loaded. When the user scroll down to bottom of the news section, increase the index by 1 and trigger the function again, which will fetch the next 5 news feeds.

I've implemented this concept in custom auto complete text box in my project and its works pretty well.

Have fun with $(#jQuery,#Json).

Comment: Played with the LazyLoad plugin and after a few hiccups it worked great. Way easier than what I had expected to create that functionality. Thanks for the suggestion. I knew what I was looking for but had no idea what to call it, so the "lazy loading" and "on demand" helped a ton looking for possibilities.

Comment: Great..!! But I haven't used any plugin to accomplish the task. I used basic jqurey functions and html events to write my own custom js library to do that. It was interesting to write plugin our self, rather than using others. Expectations fulfilled.

Comment: I'd definitely like to see how you did that or an example of a way to manually iterate five at a time. Would it just be in the each loop saying, (i = 0; i < 5; i++) and then running that each time an action was done (say hitting a "Load More" button)?

Comment: Not like that. On page load, for the first time only 5 items will be fetched from db and will be shown in page (Not all items). When the user scroll down to the last item, i ll increase page index by 1 and make an ajax call to server which will fetch next 5 items.  The key concept of "on demand" is, the data  should be fetched only when the user request it. This is how its done.

Comment: can you point me to a simple example of how this is done? I guess I'm most confused over how to increase the page index in this way. I can set up the first part, where I just flow in 5 or a predetermined number, but after playing with this idea last night, am still at a loss on how this could be done manually.